# VGG19 .h5 file modfiying

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I'm using pretrained VGG19 in my modified neural transfer code (Gatys algorithm), but my PC doesn't allow me to use input image in original size (original height is 2499 pix, but with 20GB RAM I can use it only 1000 pix maximum)

As I read, the solution for me will be decreasing batch_size. So, my question is - how can I modify VGG19 .h5 file to change batch_size inside it? Or maybe I can override batch_size of it in my code?

Comment: The batch size is not defined or stored inside the .h5 file, its just one of the parameters of model.fit or model.predict

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the pretrained model is defined on ImageNet, the maximum input data size for a single sample is 224*224.

If you try and pass a large input, it's possible your deep learning framework will reshape it into many images to be classified at once.

Resizing your input data to 224*224, you will run with a single image (batch size of 1).

You could make a custom implementation of your model to take larger input sizes.  However sizing down to 224*224 generally gets good results, depending on the task.